# НЕ: слитно или раздельно. Почему?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как пишется не- в данном предложении: "И только через много лет я понял, как черствеет душа, когда долго живёшь (не)дома." Почему?

Answer (score 1):

**Дома** (как и *домой*) является отыменным *наречием*.

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5

По правилам слитного и раздельного написания с НЕ наречий, оканчивающихся на буквы, отличные от **-о/-е**, слитно пишутся *только* те наречия, которые без НЕ не употребляются, остальные же пишутся раздельно. 
https://interneturok.ru/lesson/russian/7-klass/bglava-4-narechieb/slitnoe-i-razdelnoe-napisanie-ne-s-narechiyami-na-o-i-e-2

Поэтому правильно в нашем случае "**не дома**".

Answer (score 0):

Отрицательная частица "не" имеет свои **отдельные** правила правописания почти что с каждой частью речи. Соответственно, для того чтобы понять, как писать данную частицу с каким-либо словом, выясним его часть речи. Слово "дом" (и, соответственно, все его падежные формы) является существительным , поэтому подчиняется стандартным правилам написания, нужным из которых в сложившейся ситуации является возможность либо невозможность замены слова с частицей "не" синонимом с соответствующим значением, но уже лишённого неё. После некоторых рассуждений получаем, что такое слово подобрать не получается, следовательно необходимо писать "не" отдельно от слова "дом".